# I have an array of objects. I want to randomly output objects whose sum of values ​is equal to eight

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, sum, conditional-statements

```
    
const obj = 
    [
        {noir: 1},
        {croch: 0.5},
        {doubleCroch: 1},
        {triollet: 1.5},
        {quatreDouble: 2} 

    
];
```

desired output example:

2, 2, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 2

```
 for (var i = 0 ; i < obj.length ; i++ ){
        var randomItem = obj[Math.floor(Math.random()*obj.length )];
        
    }
```

That brings me five random items. But I want to have elements whose sum of values ​​is equal to eight.

It looks like a condition inside the random

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a couple options here:

#### 1. The foolproof approach

You calculate and collect all the possible combinations that sum up to 8. Then you pick one combination at random. This might be computationally expensive, especially since you seem to allow for duplicates. Not trivial to implement.

#### 2. The happy-go-lucky approach

You keep picking elements at random from your object as you're doing and keep track of the sum. If the sum hits 8, you have a winning combination. If it surpasses 8, you start over from scratch. A lot easier to implement, but might theoretically run infinitely.

#### 3. The over-engineered approach

You start out the same as in the previous approach, but if the sum surpasses 8, you discard the last selected element and pick another one. This would require you to keep track of all the elements you've already tried for every picked element because you might be required to backtrack further than the last selected element. The would be the hardest to implement.